# Simultaneous paste and copy of selection text

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, copy-paste, keystroke

**Background**
I want to be able to select some text, hit a keystroke that pastes what is on the clipboard over that selection, but at the same time copying that selection to the clipboard.  I often find myself doing this operation when switching variables, etc from place to place.

**Example**

First sentence here, I need to switch it with the second sentence below.   (ctrl-c)
...
Second sentence here, I am going to put this where the first one is.

///////

First sentence here, I need to switch it with the second sentence below.
...
First sentence here, I need to switch it with the second sentence below. (ctrl-"vc" after selecting second sentence, first sentence pasted, second sentence copied now)

///////

Second sentence here, I am going to put this where the first one is. (ctrl-v)

First sentence here, I need to switch it with the second sentence below.

**My question**
Does anyone know if any IDE/software supports such a paste/copy functionality?  Has anyone ever run into this?

More specifically, does any one know how to set up a keyboard shortcut to do this in sublime text 2?

Comment: or is there a way to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Here is something http://www.macstories.net/mac/copyswap-for-mac-lets-you-simultaneously-copy-and-paste-text/

Comment: Not exactly what you want because it adds one more step, but saves me a lot of time: https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-clipboard-history

Comment: that kind of stuff is all I have been able to find for windows as well - but I had not found one for sublime!  Thanks!  I will try it out next week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a plugin. I threw this together rather quickly. I don't do anything special for multiple cursors (though it should take the content of multiple cursors as well as paste to all the proper locations).

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class PasteAndCopyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        current_content = []
        cursors = view.sel()
        for cursor in cursors:
            current_content.append(view.substr(cursor))

        for cursor in cursors:
            view.replace(edit, cursor, sublime.get_clipboard())

        sublime.set_clipboard("\n".join(current_content))
```

After you save the plugin, use `paste_and_copy` as the the command for your key binding or command palette entry.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!  This is awesome.  Thank you!